# Evil circles - a cryptic clue

Tags: cryptic-clues

> Evil circles constantly observing the head and foot of the Spanish kill (7)

What word is indicated?

> The def is one word, and the clue itself involves some context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hold up, I think I see what's going on here. I reckon we're looking at the latest puzzle on PSE where the answer is:

> **PICKLES** (for those not in the know, this is quite a meme right now...)

Explanation:

> '*Evil*' here is intended as the definition - this is not the usual synonym of 'pickles' according to the dictionary, but as per recent discussions in the chatrooms there are certainly some people who would absolutely equate the two as synonymous.
>
>  *circles constantly* = **PI**, the mathematical *constant* with close connections to *circles* (formulae for circumference, area, etc.);
>
>  *observing* = **C**, because it sounds like 'see';
>
>  *the head and foot of the Spanish kill*... Purists might argue there's some surplus words to the wordplay here, but '*the head and foot of... KILL*' would be the first and last letters of the word: **KL**. Meanwhile, the two-letter country abbreviation for Spain is **ES**.
>
>  Combining all of these, we have our 'evil' - **PICKLES** - and another pickle-themed puzzle on the site!